# Select only fields using SOQL

Tags: soql

Is it possible to select only fields using `SOQL`? I mean to select fields without selecting whole `SObjects`?

For example, is it possible to select a `List<Name>` of names of accounts, such that accounts have `Rating = 'Warm'`?

I know about

```
List<Account> = [
    SELECT Name
    FROM Account
    WHERE Rating = 'Warm`
];
```

But I would like my list to have only names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not directly. You need to write your own loop e.g.:

```
List<String> names = new List<String>();
for (Account a : [
        select Name
        from Account
        where Rating = ‘Warm’
        order by Name
        ) {
    names.add(a.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the general sense, no, you cannot do this. The single exception to this by way of ID types using AggregateResult:

```
Set<Id> accountIds = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
  SELECT AccountId Id
  FROM Opportunity
  GROUP BY AccountId]).keySet();
```

This works by aliasing the lookup field to the special value `Id` (case sensitive), which we briefly turn in to a map, and get the key set for that map.

Obviously, this will not work for any other type of field, in which case you'll have to use a for loop, as mentioned by Keith's answer.